# How to configure nginx, access from web browser using ansible playbook?

Tags: nginx, ansible, ansible-playbook

I have an ansible playbook to install nginx. But when I type ip address I cannot access the server. Service is running fine.

```
---
- name: Install nginx
  hosts: nginx
  become: true

  tasks:
  - name: Add epel-release repo
    yum:
      name: epel-release
      state: present

  - name: Install nginx
    yum:
      name: nginx
      state: present

  - name: Ansible copy file to remote server
    copy:
      src: /root/ansible/nginx.conf
      dest: /etc/nginx
      force: yes


  - name: Start NGiNX
    service:
      name: nginx
      state: started
      enabled: yes
```

How can I develop this script to access from ip address?

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http 
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=https
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Can I use above commands in playbook?

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/firewalld_module.html

Comment: Can you give me an example? I want to set public access. If I add http and https, is it okay?

Comment: Please scrollt down on the link. You can find examples there. I think http and https should be enough for a webserver.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this question.

```
  - firewalld:
      service: https
      permanent: yes
      state: enabled

  - firewalld:
     zone: public
     service: http
     permanent: yes
     state: enabled

  - name: Bounce firewalld
    service:
      name: firewalld
      state: restarted
```